# Google Analytics Not Tracking Event

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following script between the head tags.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-2', 'mywebsite.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

then i have the following script in the body with the necessary //Server Connect. Trying to pull the "event" into analytics. Getting firm_website, firm_name, firm_location, and firm_slogan and is pulling the necessary information into their pages from the database. but, having issues actually getting the event to appear in analytics. We would have to update 2,000 plus pages and that is really not an option.
thanks for the help. I'm a little knowledgeable when it comes to php and need help coding the below.

```
<?php
//Display Firm Text
echo '<p class="alignCenter"><font size="+1" color="#930"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.' . $firm_website . '" onclick="ga('send','event','Outgoing Links','. $firm_website .')"><strong>' . $firm_name . '</strong></a></font><br />';
echo '' . $firm_location . '<br />';
echo '<i>' . $firm_slogan . '</i></p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may come from the use of single quotes and double quotes. You are using single quotes to define your php string, and double quotes in your HTML, which is ok. However, in the ga function, you are using single quotes where you should be usin double quotes I think.
I would try something like the below:

```
<?php
//Display Firm Text
echo '<p class="alignCenter"><font size="+1" color="#930"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.' . $firm_website . '" onclick="ga("send","event","Outgoing Links","'. $firm_website .'")"><strong>' . $firm_name . '</strong></a></font><br />';
echo '' . $firm_location . '<br />';
echo '<i>' . $firm_slogan . '</i></p>';
?>
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried the double quotes a while back. The page actually works but google analytics is not picking up on the link. Could it be that it does not understand the .$firm_website. as it may need a "real web address" Or is it maybe sending the request faster than google can pick up the link. was reading this but can not really make sense of it all. [link]https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events[/link]

Answer (score 0):

Like Greg, in your code :

```
onclick="ga('send','event','Outgoing Links','. $firm_website .')"
```

Will give you that :

```
onclick="ga('send','event','Outgoing Links',www.site.com)"
```

So, you forget the ' :

```
onclick="ga('send','event','Outgoing Links',\''. $firm_website .'\')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code below - Tested and is working as expected.

```
<?php
//Display Firm Text
echo '<p class="alignCenter"><font size="+1" color="#930"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.' . $firm_website . '" onclick="ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'Outgoing Links\',\''. $firm_website .'\')" <strong>' . $firm_name . '</strong></a></font><br />';
echo '' . $firm_location . '<br />';
echo ('<i>' . $firm_slogan . '</i></p>');
?>
```